# Wildcard SSL certificate not working with Chrome's built-in Flash player

Tags: flash, google-chrome, ssl-certificate, rtmp

I'm currently working on a system that has a Flash Client talking to a remote application server via RTMPS.  The Flash Client and the app server handshake using an SSL wildcard certificate.  For instance, if my app server is on the host "blah.test.mysite.com", the SSL certificate I have (via DigiCert) is for *.test.mysite.com.  I have tested this setup and it works on IE9, Firefox 3/4 and Safari 5 with the Flash 10.2 r154 plugin, but it does not work on Chrome 10.

I believe the problem is Chrome's built-in Flash player.  In Chrome, if I go to "about:plugins", click the "Details" button on the right and click "disable" next to the Flash player plugin located at "C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\Application\10.0.648.205\gcswf32.dll" and try again (using the system plugin located at "C:\Windows\SysWOW64\Macromed\Flash\NPSWF32.dll"), everything works.  But whenever I enable Chrome's built-in Flash player, my SSL handshake from my Flash client to my application server ALWAYS fails.  The two Flash players (Chrome built-in and Windows installed) are the exact same version.

Does Google modify their built-in Flash player in any way that could cause this?  Does Chrome treat the built-in Flash player differently than the one installed in the OS proper?  Any ideas at all as to what could cause this?

Thanks!

Comment: So for anyone who runs into this, it has to do with how Chrome sandboxes the Flash player.  If Chrome is run with the "--disable-flash-sandbox" command line argument, the issue disappears.  No solution yet, but I'll post when I find one.

Comment: Seeing the same issue with non-wildcard SSL certificate - it appears to be a problem with RTMPS in general. Thanks for replying with your further findings, you saved me time.

Comment: Still an issue for me on Ubuntu, adobe link https://bugbase.adobe.com/index.cfm?event=selectBug&CFGRIDKEY=3057375

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after a long discussion and a silent period, I've gotten confirmation that this is actually a bug in the current Flash Player and is being worked on.